# Multiple Plots in one PDF file

Tags: r, plot

I tried this:

```
for(i in 1:10) {
  pdf("filename.pdf",onefile=TRUE)
  plot(...)
}
dev.off()
```

And

```
for(i in 1:10) {
  pdf("filename.pdf",onefile=TRUE)
  plot(...)
  dev.off()
}
```

But it does work. How is this can be achieved? I need a new page for every plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are opening a new pdf in the loop. Try opening the pdf beforehand and closing it after the loop.

```
pdf("filename.pdf",onefile=TRUE)    
for(i in 1:10) {
  plot(...)
}
dev.off()
```